# Simple jQuery script required to create show/hide continuous loop

Tags: jquery

I have to the best of my knowledge researched the questions on this forum, but not quite got the answer.
I am a newbie in terms of jQuery.
I  have got this div

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="1" class="trip">Item1</div>
    <div id="2" class="trip">Item2</div>
    <div id="3" class="trip">Item3></div>
</div>
```

And I want to fade in each div in turn, then hide and fade in the next div.
I want this to do a continuous loop through the divs until the visitor leaves the page.
I need step by step help to achieve this.
I am new on stackoverflow, but I learn fast so bear with me :)

Any help is much appreciated.
//Ot_Gu

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822524/continuous-movement-animation-with-jquery

Comment: do you mean you need 'Carousel'?

Comment: Please try to write the code yourself first and post the attempt here when you're stuck

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372301/how-to-write-a-loop-in-jquery-which-waits-for-each-function-to-complete-before-c

Comment: 55 "best" carousel plugins: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html - there is bound to be one in there that does exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function and use it as `fadeOut`'s callback, the function will be called when an element is faded out.

```
var $elem = $('#main .trip'), l = $elem.length, i = 0;

function comeOn() {
    $elem.eq(i % l).fadeIn(700, function() {
        $elem.eq(i % l).fadeOut(700, comeOn);
        i++;
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MtmxN/

Comment: ...Is there a way to set a length of time before it starts fading out?

Comment: ...and could this length of time be a variable - so that for example, if the div contained a video it could play to end and then fade out.

Comment: @Ot_Gu Yes, you can use `delay` method  `var d = 1000; $elem.eq(i % l).delay(d).fadeOut(700, comeOn);` If it's a video you can call the function on it's `end` event.

Answer (score 1):

This is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMPFZ/)

```
function name_of_the_function() {
    $('.trip').each(function (index) { //for each element with class 'trip'
        $(this).delay(index * 1000).animate({ //delay 1000 ms which is the duration of the animation
            opacity: 1 //animate the opacity from 0 to 1
        }, {
            duration: 1000, //duration
            complete: function () { //when the animation is finished
                $(this).css({
                    opacity: 0 //turn the opacity from 1 to 0 without animation
                });
                if (index == 2) { //if the index == 2 which means we are in the last element in this case as we have 3 elements (0,1,2)
                    name_of_the_function(); //go back to the function
                }
            }
        });

    });
}

name_of_the_function(); //call the function at first
```

and the css I used:

```
.trip {
    opacity:0;
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it using recursion with a list of element IDs for a more flexible solution.

```
var ids = ["#1","#2","#3"],
    time = 1000;


function cycleShowHide (i,ids,time) {
    if (i>=ids.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    //hide previous
    if (i==0) {
        $(ids[ids.length-1]).hide(time);
    } else {
        $(ids[i-1]).hide(time);
    }
    //show next and repeat
    $(ids[i]).show(time, function(){
        i++;
        cycleShowHide(i);
    }
}

cycleShowHide(0,ids,time);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use jquery toggle

```
<div id="main" style='display:none'>
     <div id="1" class="trip">Item1</div>
     <div id="2" class="trip">Item2</div>
     <div id="3" class="trip">Item3></div> 
</div>
<button id='mb'>Chick here</button>
```

write in script tag..

```
 $("#mb").click(function(){
     $('#main').toggle();
 });
```