# Appending item view one by one with Marionnete

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I would like to create a fancy fade in function that appends 'li's one by one in my composite view.

It would append li[0] first and than next one after 5000ms and another after 5000ms and so on.

How can I achieve this effect? Right now I coded only simple fade in:

```
class List.ConferenceSingle extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "conference/list/_conference_single"
    tagName: "li"
    onRender: =>
      @$el.fadeIn(2000) 


class List.Conference extends App.Views.CompositeView
   template: "conference/list/_conference"
   itemView: List.ConferenceSingle
   itemViewContainer: "ul"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mechanism of collectionView is to prepare all child views and show them all together.

So the effect on itemView in your question won't happen because the collectionView rendered in a whole.

To achieve this effect, you need to mimic a fake effect on collectionView's DOM object but not the itemViews.

```
class List.Conference extends App.Views.CompositeView
  onRender: -> # or onDomRefresh? not tested
    @childElementsFadeIn()

  # This will wait for each li to fadeIn completely, and then next
  # This is again a fake operation as `each` is executed without any delay
  childElementsFadeIn: ->
    duration = 5000;
    @$el.each (index, element) ->
      $(element).delay(index * duration).fadeIn()
```

*Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2372421/1721198 for jQuery part*